# How to get some text from an url multiple times?

Tags: java, android, url, web, connect

**This question is solved**

Sry for the title -_-
I am trying to create an app that get some text from a webpage. when you click on the "next" button you will go to the next page and update the text. The thing I have problem with is when you click the "next" button the text isn't updated. preferably I just want to run the code below to update the text. I think I have narrowed it down to a problem with the way i set up a connection.

```
private static BufferedReader page;

public  void checkPage(String website, int number){

    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    String line = "start";

    try {
        url = new URL(website + number);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        page = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        while (line != null) {

            line = page.readLine();
            checkLine(line);    
        }
        connection.disconnect();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

checkLine() does some funky stuff to get the text I'm after..
It feels like I am missing something obvious..

the current setup is that I have a class called "GetDataFromPage" witch saves the data in some private String variables, then im using some public methods within "GetDataFromPage" to extract the data for use..

The problem is that the data in the "GetDataFromPage" Class doesn't seam to want to uppdate when i call data.checkPage(web, url+1); where data is GetDataFromPage

**Update**

I am frekin stupid.. all it was were some booleans that i forgot to reset enabling reading of data. that is what happens when you write code late at night..

Comment: What do you get from object connection? Is it null? Do you get an Exception? What do you get from object page? At this stage of debugging, it helps if you tell what the  symptoms are.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private BufferedReader page;       // changed

public  void checkPage(String website, int number){

    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    String line = "null";       // changed

    try {
        url = new URL(website + number);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        page = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        while ((line=page.readLine()) != null) {   // changed

                                                  // changed
            checkLine(line);    
        }
        connection.disconnect();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: well changing the BufferedReader to none static didn't really help but might be a bit cleaner.. Sorry for not mentioning how I'm saving the data. the current setup is that I have a class called "GetDataFromPage" witch saves the data in some private String variables, then im using some public methods within "GetDataFromPage" to extract the data for use.. 

The problem is that the data in the "GetDataFromPage" Class doesn't seam to want to uppdate when i call  data.checkPage(web, url+1); where data is GetDataFromPage

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't figure out what exactly do you want, as currently you're just grabbing 1 line from the page, so you end up having just the last line in the line varible. Where do you save it, in your checkline function?

Comment: well changing the BufferedReader to none static didn't really help but might be a bit cleaner.. Sorry for not mentioning how I'm saving the data. the current setup is that I have a class called "GetDataFromPage" witch saves the data in some private String variables, then im using some public methods within "GetDataFromPage" to extract the data for use.. The problem is that the data in the "GetDataFromPage" Class doesn't seam to want to uppdate when i call data.checkPage(web, url+1); where data is GetDataFromPage

Answer (score 0):

well changing the BufferedReader to none static didn't really help but might be a bit cleaner..

Sorry for not mentioning how I'm saving the data. the current setup is that I have a class called "GetDataFromPage" witch saves the data in some private String variables, then im using some public methods within "GetDataFromPage" to extract the data for use..

The problem is that the data in the "GetDataFromPage" Class doesn't seam to want to uppdate when i call data.checkPage(web, url+1); where data is GetDataFromPage

**UPDATE**

I am frekin stupid.. all it was were some booleans that i forgot to reset enabling reading of data. that is what happens when you write code late at night..